# In a multiple MatSelect, a re-enabled checkbox shows as disabled

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using Angular Material, I want to disable the checkboxes within a multiple <MatSelect> for a period of time (as data is retrieved from an API). I can successfully do this, however the CSS class for the checkbox does not change back. In other words, the checkbox is functionally enabled, but the CSS displays as disabled. Is this a Material defect or something I can fix?

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqzx99

**Component:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChildren(MatOption) matSelectOptions: QueryList<MatOption>;

  public isPaused = false;
  public optionData = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];

  /**
   * Disable MatSelect checkboxes for 2 seconds
   */
  public disableCheckboxes(): void {
    this.isPaused = true;
    this.matSelectOptions.forEach(option => option.disabled = true);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isPaused = false;
      this.matSelectOptions.forEach(option => option.disabled = false);
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select multiple
                [disabled]="isPaused"
                (selectionChange)="disableCheckboxes()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of optionData">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-placeholder>Example</mat-placeholder>
</mat-form-field>

<p id="loadingStatus">{{isPaused ? 'Pausing…' : ''}}</p>
```

Comment: why do you disable the mat-select and the options separately? have you tried to do just 1 of the actions (or the mat-select or only the options)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that programatically disabling the MatOptions objects is not really a good idea.

So using just *isPaused* for select and options works fine

**Component:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChildren(MatOption) matSelectOptions: QueryList<MatOption>;

  public isPaused = false;
  public optionData = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];

  /**
   * Disable MatSelect checkboxes for 2 seconds
   */
  public disableCheckboxes(): void {
    this.isPaused = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isPaused = false;
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<h3>Disabled MatSelect Checkbox Problem:</h3>

<hr>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select multiple
                [disabled]="isPaused"
                (selectionChange)="disableCheckboxes()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of optionData" [disabled]="isPaused">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-placeholder>Example</mat-placeholder>
</mat-form-field>

<p id="loadingStatus">{{isPaused ? 'Pausing…' : ''}}</p>
```

Comment: You'll notice that this method only disables the placeholder, not the options in the container. In order to disable the options and checkmarks themselves you have to disable them individually, in this case via @ViewChildren.

Comment: Well I disagree, in my example you can't click the options while they are disabled, as the [disabled] attribute affects both the style and the user interaction. You can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled)